# Web service returning multiple values in a single row delimited by tags

Tags: java, xml, web-services, netbeans, tags

I need to build a web service that returns multiple rows from database and each row should containt several fields delimited by tags. I created this ws using Netbeans and it is running on a glassfish server. I only managed to return tagged rows containing a string made by concatenated values (fields). Can you please give me some advice on how to modify my return?

Now my web service returns as following:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:extractCSResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">
            <ROW xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"><Firstname>Mark</Firstname><Lastname>Thomas</Lastname><ID>1112546</ID></ROW>
            <ROW xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"><Firstname>Mike</Firstname><Lastname>Jackson</Lastname><ID>1112547</ID></ROW>
        </ns2:extractCSResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My return needs to look like this:

```
<S:Body>
        <ns2:extractCSResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">
            <ROWS>
                <ROW>
                    <Firstname>Mark</Firstname>
                    <Lastname>Thomas</Lastname>
                    <IDname>1112546</IDname>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                    <Firstname>Mike</Firstname>
                    <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
                    <IDname>1112547</IDname>
                </ROW>
            </ROWS>
        </ns2:extractCSResponse>
    </S:Body>
```

Java code below:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "GetCS2")
@Stateless()
public class GetCS2 {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "extractCS")
    @WebResult(name = "ROW")
    public List extractCS()
    {
        List l = new ArrayList();

        //username and password for database connection
        String userName = "username";
        String password = "password";

              //db connection
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

                String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.19.125.222:1433"+";databaseName=Test";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from list");

                //loop through selection
                while(rs.next())
                {               
                    l.add("<Firstname>" + rs.getString("fn") + "</Firstname>" + "<Lastname>" + rs.getString("ln") + "</Lastname>" + "<IDname>" + rs.getDate("ID") + "</ID>");
                }

                //close connections
                stmt.close();
                rs.close();
                con.close();

            } catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cE)
            {
                System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: " + cE.toString());
            }

            return l;

    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my answer with a simple example. hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** to show basic example in case the links will one day no longer have this information.

I generally try to avoid building `xml` by concatenating strings. This is error prone, can contain invalid `xml` data (what if a name contains `&` or  `<` or any other special characters which can't appear in `xml`?) and hard to change once there is new data or something changes in the database structure.
Take a look at [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) for mapping objects to `xml` files.

Basically you will need to create a custom class representing your database `object` and a wrapper for multiple ones. Populate objects from your DB, add them to the wrapper, then use `JAXB` to write to `xml` Here is an example [JAXB Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html#jaxb)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
public class Person{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String idName;

  ....
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "PersonWrapper")
public class PersonWrapper{
   private List<Person> persons;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "PersonList")
   @XmlElement(name = "Person")
   public List getPersons(){
      return persons;
   }
   ....
}
```

Then in your code, add `resultset` from database into a list. Then add the list to the wrapper. Finally create `xml` file from the wrapper.

```
List<Person> personList=new ArrayList<Person>();
while(rs.next())
{               
    personList.add(new Person(rs.getString("fn"),rs.getString("lastName"),...));
}

PersonWrapper pw=new PersonWrapper();
pw.setPersons(personList);

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PersonWrapper.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

//write to system.out or any other OutputStream (ByteArrayOutputStream)
m.marshal(pw, System.out); 

//OR write to xml file
m.marshal(pw, new File("person.xml"));
```

If you want to return a `String`, then simply convert `OutputStream` to `String` and display the results. You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` with `baos.toString(desiredEncoding);`

Comment: Thank you! I successfully returned the XML in the way I wanted. Basically I had to create a new Person class and I had to use things like: XmlElement, XmlAttribute and XmlSeeAlso (import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also returned a List<Person>, just like you said. Thanks!